# What is the hardware requirement for alfresco on windows platform?

Tags: alfresco

I am planning to use alfresco. What is the hardware requirement for installing it? Do I need a windows server machine to run? Can I install it in a windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hardware requirements highly depend on your requirements & expected usage (number of documents/transactions, concurrent users etc.)!

You can run Alfresco as in a simple Desktop OS (e.g. Win7). You should have at least 1GB RAM available for Alfresco (that means your machine should have min. 2GB).

Answer (score 3):

To add onto what Alfrescian has posted, I also recommend you review the "Installation" Chapter in the Alfresco One documentation.  There you should find information about environment and architecture validation which should provide you information on base hardware needs.

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/ch-install.html

If you plan to run Alfresco in a production environment, I highly recommend you go with Alfresco Enterprise.  Deploying Alfresco Enterprise will further constrain what platforms you may use.  You can find the support platforms information here: [Alfresco Supported Platforms](http://www.alfresco.com/services/subscription/supported-platforms)

The supported platforms documentation will give you an idea of what platforms you will need to be able to run deploy Alfresco.